Error message while using "pyspark" command in CMD
I've installed pyspark using pip install pyspark command in CMD.
After when I ran pyspark command in CMD I'm getting below error message.

Need resolution how I can fix this. I've checked below to fix this issue but no luck still
Checked if environment variables are properly configured.

Use python --version to check if python binary is on the PATH since Spark isn't looking for py launcher

@OneCricketeer check and working fine returning same version in screen shot above

The second part of the error suggests turning off aliases https://stackoverflow.com/a/71514723/2308683
